# Loading map to ngSwitch child scope using ElementRef in Ionic

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, ionic-framework, angularjs-scope, ng-switch

I'm trying to access a *ngSwitchCase* view using *@ViewChild* and *ElementRef* to load a google map in my Ionic 3 app. I understand the *ngSwitch* creates its own scope but is it not accessible in anyway so I can load the map from google to the  *#map id="map" div* in the *mapView ngSwitchCase*?

**page.ts**

```
//the import
import { ElementRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-views',
  templateUrl: 'views.html'
})
export class ViewsPage {

//the attribute in the export class
@ViewChild('map') mapElement : ElementRef;
views: string = "listView";

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {}

  //the functions 
  ionViewDidLoad(){
    this.loadMap();
  }

  loadMap(){
    this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((position) => {
      let latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
      // initializing map attributes
      let mapOptions = {
        center: latLng,
        zoom: 15,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      };
      this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.mapElement.nativeElement, mapOptions);
    });
  }
}
```

**page.html**

```
<ion-toolbar>
  <ion-segment [(ngModel)]="views">
    <ion-segment-button value="mapView">
      Map
    </ion-segment-button>
    <ion-segment-button value="listView">
      List
    </ion-segment-button>
  </ion-segment>
</ion-toolbar>

<ion-content padding>
  <div [ngSwitch]="views">
    <ion-list *ngSwitchCase="'mapView'">
      <ion-item>
        <div #map id="map"></div>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>

    <ion-list *ngSwitchCase="'listView'">
      //other stuff
    </ion-list> 
  </div> 
</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 2):

ngSwitch creates and destroys the respective DOM element dynamically. Since you start your default view initialized to list view with

```
views: string = "listView";
```

the ion-list which is

```
<ion-list *ngSwitchCase="'mapView'">
```

does not exist in DOM. Consequently, the div with map, which is child of ion-list does not exist. Hence `mapElement : ElementRef` is null. Its possible that if you start with default segment view with map like

```
views: string = "mapView";
```

your code might run and create the map for once. Just try it. It works for me. **Note** that on switching segments the map is destroyed and may not be created again since your `loadMap()` only runs one time.

At this point, you have two options.

1. Instead of ngSwitch (which creates/destroys elements), use show/hide Map and List.

   **page.scss**

   ```
    .hide 
    {
     display: none !important;
    }
   ```

   **page.html**

   ```
   <ion-content padding>
       <div #map id="map" [ngClass]="{ 'hide': views != 'mapView' }"></div>
       <div [ngClass]="{ 'hide': views != 'listView' }">
           <ion-list >
            //other stuff
           </ion-list> 
       </div> 
   </ion-content>
   ```
2. Have a tabs component with a Map tab and a List tab.

   **page.ts**

   ```
   import { ElementRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
   import { ListPage } from '../list/list';
   import { MapPage } from '../map/map';

   @Component({
     selector: 'page-views',
     templateUrl: 'views.html'
   })
   export class ViewsPage {

      views: string = "listView";

      tab1Root = MapPage;
      tab2Root = ListPage;

      constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {}

   }
   ```

   **page.html**

   ```
     <ion-content>
       <ion-tabs>
        <ion-tab [root]="tab1Root" tabTitle="Map" tabIcon="map"></ion-tab>
        <ion-tab [root]="tab2Root" tabTitle="List" tabIcon="list"></ion-tab>
       </ion-tabs>
     </ion-content>
   ```

   **map.ts**

   ```
   .
   .
   export class MapPage { 

     @ViewChild('map') mapElement : ElementRef;

     constructor(){}

     ionViewDidLoad(){
       this.loadMap();
     }

     loadMap(){
       //stuff here
     }
    }
   ```

Also, I noticed that you are creating a list of maps with

```
<ion-list *ngSwitchCase="'mapView'">
  <ion-item>
     <div #map id="map"></div>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Don't you want just one map? Shouldn't this be like

```
 <div [ngSwitch]="views">
    <div #map id="map" *ngSwitchCase="'mapView'"></div>
    <ion-list *ngSwitchCase="'listView'">
    .
    .
```

Comment: Thanks Vishal! Your point about making one map is well taken, I will try setting the default to
    `<div #map id="map" *ngSwitchCase="'mapView'"></div>`
But will have to address the loading issue

Comment: Edited my answer with potential solutions to overcome ngSwitch's create/destroy DOM

Comment: Awesome, using solution#1 this until we have a proper implementation.